# Как улучшить свой код?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм, рефакторинг, чистый-код

Сейчас читаю `Чистый код` Мартина и стараюсь улучшить свой код . У меня есть абстрактный класс `Filter` :

```
package filters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.lang.Math.pow;

/**
* This abstract class allows to define certain filter properties
* and writing a detailed implementation of selected methods for the
* low-pass filter and high-pass filter.
*
* @autor Andrii Shyrokov
*/

public abstract class Filter {

/**
 * Private field storing magnitudes
 */
private double[] magnitudeCoordinate;
/**
 * Private field storing omegas
 */
private double[] cutoffFrequencyCoordinate;

/**
 * @return transfer function as a string
 */
public abstract String getTransferFunction();

/**
 * This method returns the absolute value of the transfer function at specific
 * frequency.
 *
 * @param omega is a component of the Laplace transform variable s=j*omega.
 * @return absolute value of a transfer function in the frequency domain.
 */
protected abstract double getAbsoluteValue(int omega) throws Exception;

/**
 * This method use 20 log |H(jw)|to  compute  the  magnitude  in  dB.
 *
 * @param omega is a component of the Laplace transform variable s = j*omega.
 * @return magnitude in dB.
 */
protected abstract double getAmplitudeRatio(int omega) throws Exception;

/**
 * This method creates a random filter randomly generating an amplifier and
 * time constant.
 */
public abstract Filter createRandomFilter() throws Exception;

/**
 * This method mutate transfer function of the filter. Mutation is a genetic
 * operator used to maintain genetic diversity from one generation of a population
 * of genetic algorithm chromosomes to the next. It is analogous to biological mutation.
 */
public abstract void mutateFilterTransferFunction() throws Exception;

/**
 * This method doing recombination of the transfer function. Crossover, also
 * called recombination, is a genetic operator used to combine the genetic
 * information of two parents to generate new offspring.
 */
public abstract void recombination(Filter filter) throws Exception;

/**
 * @return an array of magnitudes.
 */
public double[] getMagnitudeCoordinate() {
    return this.magnitudeCoordinate;
}

public double[] getCutoffFrequencyCoordinate() {
    return this.cutoffFrequencyCoordinate;
}

/**
 * This method calculates an array of magnitudes using information
 * about content of the omega's array.
 */
void calculateMagnitudePlot() throws Exception {
    double[] magnitudeCoordinate = new double[21];
    double[] cutoffFrequencyCoordinate = new double[21];
    for (int i = -10; i < 11; i++) {
        try {
            getAmplitudeRatio(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        magnitudeCoordinate[i + 10] = getAmplitudeRatio(i);
        cutoffFrequencyCoordinate[i + 10] = pow(10, i);
    }
    this.magnitudeCoordinate = magnitudeCoordinate;
    this.cutoffFrequencyCoordinate = cutoffFrequencyCoordinate;
}

ArrayList<Double> getCutoffFrequency() {
    ArrayList<Double> cutoffFrequency = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = -10; i < 11; i++) {
        cutoffFrequency.add(1 / pow(10, i));
    }
    return cutoffFrequency;
}

public abstract int getFilterKey();

public abstract double getLPFTimeConstant();

public abstract double getHPFTimeConstant();

public abstract double getLPFAmplifier();
```

}

И наследник (их на самом деле много, но они похожи в реализации):

```
package filters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class LowPassFilter extends Filter {

private final int filterKey = 0;
private double amplifier;
private String transferFunction;
private double timeConstant;
private ArrayList<Double> cutoffFrequency;

public LowPassFilter(double amplifier, double timeConstant) throws Exception {
    cutoffFrequency = getCutoffFrequency();
    this.amplifier = amplifier;
    this.timeConstant = timeConstant;
    transferFunction = getTransferFunction();
    calculateMagnitudePlot();
}

public LowPassFilter() {
    cutoffFrequency = getCutoffFrequency();
}

@Override
public String getTransferFunction() {
    transferFunction = amplifier + "/" + "(" + timeConstant + "s+" + 1 + ")";
    return transferFunction;
}

@Override
protected double getAbsoluteValue(int omega) throws Exception {
    if (omega < -10) throw new Exception("The number is less than 10^-10, current value: " + pow(10, omega));
    if (omega > 10) throw new Exception("The number is more than 10^10,  current value: " + pow(10, omega));
    double numerator = amplifier;
    double denominator = sqrt(1 + pow(pow(10, omega), 2) * pow(timeConstant, 2));
    return numerator / denominator;
}

@Override
protected double getAmplitudeRatio(int omega) throws Exception {
    return 20 * log10(getAbsoluteValue(omega));
}

@Override
public Filter createRandomFilter() throws Exception {
    timeConstant = getCutoffFrequency().get(new Random().nextInt(21));
    amplifier = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;
    return new LowPassFilter(amplifier, timeConstant);
}

@Override
public void mutateFilterTransferFunction() throws Exception {
    cutoffFrequency = getCutoffFrequency();
    int LPFMutationPosition = new Random().nextInt(2);
    switch (LPFMutationPosition) {
        case 0:
            amplifier = new Random().nextInt(2) + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            timeConstant = cutoffFrequency.get(new Random().nextInt(21));
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    transferFunction = getTransferFunction();
    calculateMagnitudePlot();
}

@Override
public void recombination(Filter filter) throws Exception {
    cutoffFrequency = getCutoffFrequency();
    int LPFRecombinationPosition = new Random().nextInt(2);
    switch (LPFRecombinationPosition) {
        case 0:
            if (filter.getFilterKey() == 1) {
                amplifier = new Random().nextInt(1) + 1;
            } else {
                amplifier = filter.getLPFAmplifier();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (filter.getFilterKey() == 0) {
                timeConstant = filter.getLPFTimeConstant();
            } else if (filter.getFilterKey() == 1) {
                timeConstant = filter.getHPFTimeConstant();
            } else if (filter.getFilterKey() == 2) {
                timeConstant = filter.getLPFTimeConstant();
            } else if (filter.getFilterKey() == 3) {
                timeConstant = filter.getLPFTimeConstant();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    transferFunction = getTransferFunction();
    calculateMagnitudePlot();
}

@Override
public int getFilterKey() {
    return this.filterKey;
}

@Override
public double getLPFTimeConstant() {
    return this.timeConstant;
}

@Override
public double getHPFTimeConstant() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public double getLPFAmplifier() {
    return this.amplifier;
}
}
```

1. В книге было написано, что идеальный код - когда нет комментариев, точнее они не нужны для понимания сути. Но правильно ли будет их оставить, ведь в проекте затрагивается генетика, электроника и т.п.
2. Также `switch case` ( в классе `LowPassFilter` ), следуя Мартину, стоило бы заменить полиморфизмом. Но мне кажется, что в моем случае это не совсем уместно ( или уместно?)
3. Хотел бы узнать какие по-вашему мнению я допускаю ошибки, читаемый ли мой код.

Comment: В методах я бы посоветовал поменять числа (10,11,21...) переменными или константами, чтоб было более понятно откуда они берутся. В случае возникновения необходимости их изменить, вам придется править все методы сразу.

Comment: По строке `void calculateMagnitudePlot() throws Exception` - поднимать наверх ошибку Exception не хорошо, если вы знаете в каком месте у вас может произойти исключение создайте собственный тип исключений который может сгенерировать ваш код

Comment: В данном месте
`@Override
public String getTransferFunction() {
    transferFunction = amplifier + "/" + "(" + timeConstant + "s+" + 1 + ")";
    return transferFunction;
}`
думаю, будет лучше использовать
`return String.format("%a/(%ts+1)",amplifier,timeConstant)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**

Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы описывать цели классов/методов в публичных интерфейсах и абстрактных классах, которыми будут пользоваться другие люди. Скорее даже желательно документировать.

С другой стороны, если пользователи вашего кода **знают**, что такое `calculateMagnitudePlot` и как оно должно вычисляться, то, возможно, подробное описание и не нужно.

Вот тут(и в похожих местах) комментарий излишен, так как он не повышает понимания сути. Суть абсолютно понятна из декларации поля.

```
/**
 * Private field storing magnitudes
 */
private double[] magnitudeCoordinate;
```

**2**

По поводу `case` - у вас тут не полиморфизм нужен, а декомпозиция, поскольку, по сути, вы накладываете на метод несколько обязанностей.

**3**

Хорошим тоном считается не использовать однострочные if'ы, а в любом случае использовать блок {}

А вот тут, наоборот, вполне можно обойтись без промежуточной переменной (но это вкусовщина)

```
public String getTransferFunction() {
    transferFunction = amplifier + "/" + "(" + timeConstant + "s+" + 1 + ")";
    return transferFunction;
}
```

Ну и в целом у вас сильная недостача применения принципа единственной ответственности

Есть принципиальна необходимость отдавать реализацию этх полей/методов на откуп дочернему классу?

```
private final int filterKey = 0;
private double amplifier;
private double timeConstant;

public abstract int getFilterKey();
public abstract double getLPFTimeConstant();
public abstract double getHPFTimeConstant();
public abstract double getLPFAmplifier();
```

**UPD** Про фигурные скобки в if, for, while и т.д.

Немного цитат.

[Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces)

> Braces are used with if, else, for, do and while statements, even when
>   the body is empty or contains only a single statement.

[Oracle Java code convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

> if statements always use braces {}.

[php-src code standarts](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS)

> Always prefer::
>
> ```
> if (foo) {
>     bar;
> }
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> if(foo)bar;
> ```

[Clean code by Robert Martin](https://www.investigatii.md/uploads/resurse/Clean_Code.pdf)

```
Sometimes the body of a while or for statement is a dummy, as shown below. I don’t like
these kinds of structures and try to avoid them. When I can’t avoid them, I make sure that
the dummy body is properly indented and surrounded by braces
```

Есть много проектов, где данная ситуация специально не оговаривается, либо  допускается в случае очень простого и короткого тела (например linux kernel), но я не видел ни одного, где бы в правилах кода была явная рекомендация не использовать фигурные скобки для выделения тела оператора.

Собственно почему лучше использовать, чем не использовать. В более-менее серьезном проекте код не статичен, а постоянно меняется, причем разными людьми. В таком контексте крайне важно минимизировать возможность случайной человеческой ошибки при рефакторинге. Фигурные скобки **явно** выделяют тело оператора - захочешь, не ошибешься.

Comment: "_Хорошим тоном считается не использовать однострочные if'ы..._" - как минимум, спорно. Чем они вам не угодили? По-моему, так излишние фигурные скобки где надо и не надо, наоборот, только загромождают код. Но в любом случае, это совет из категории вкусовщины, а не разумная рекомендация.

Comment: @freim сложнее ошибиться, если в будущем, в добавок к выбросу эксепшена, потребуется добавить какую либо логику

Comment: С чего бы там ошибаться, однострочный оператор он как бы очевиден. Чтобы не заметить что там нет блока и вписать туда еще что-то, надо быть слепоглухонемым. Есть конструкции где ошибиться легко (= вместо ==, например), но однострочные `if/while` явно не из этого числа. Можно понять людей, которые литералы в условиях пишут слева (типа `1==n`), там действительно есть какое-то разумное обоснование, ну а это вкусовщина в чистом виде.

Comment: @freim однострочные if, for, while - это классический "code smells". Чем больше проект и чем больше людей над ним работает - тем выше вероятность "случайного" выстрела в ногу.

Comment: Я полистал разные списки "code smells", но такого там не обнаружил. В той же википедии, к примеру, этого нет. Так что отнесение однострочных операторов в категорию "code smells" это явно не общепринятое соглашение.

Comment: @freim Clean code, Chapter 5: Formatting, Dummy Scopes.
https://www.investigatii.md/uploads/resurse/Clean_Code.pdf

Comment: Ясно. Так считает Роберт Мартин. Знаете, частное мнение одного человека не стоит выдавать за общепринятое правило, так что давайте не будем обобщать.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел внимательнее - да он же совсем не о том пишет! Вы сами-то хоть эту книжку читали? Там говорится о том, когда исполняемого оператора вообще нет. Dummy scope, dummy.

Comment: Согласен с rjhdby. В больших проектах однострочные операторы недопустимы. За реееедким исключением. Вопрос был "как улучшить свой код". Так что, @freim, слушайте хорошие советы.

Comment: @Андрей Туманов, глупости. Вместо простого оператора `if (i == 0) ++i;` городить блок с фигурными скобками - это никак не назвать хорошим стилем. Разве что программисту построчно платят.

Comment: @АндрейТуманов Не хотелось спорить об ерунде, но раз уж завязалось... Добавил в ответ про фигурные скобки.

Comment: @freim не надо экономить на спичках.